# Why is Kotlin unable to debug Ktor?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, kotlin, ktor

I just started a simple Ktor app and set a breakpoint. But it seems I cannot debug or evaluate the interesting items:

[image]

Seems like the Kotlin Debugger just has no idea what is going on and totally messes up the Scope (Kotlin 1.3, IntelliJ 2019.1.1)?

If I am not able to debug my code and evaluate expressions (like inspecting the headers of the request or something) this is an instant no-go for me :(

Is there any special setting needed to make this work?

Comment: Which exactly Kotlin plugin version are you using?

Comment: Hello yole, I'm on 1.3.31-release-IJ2019.1-1

Comment: Please file a bug to our issue tracker: https://kotl.in/issue.